# Deleting 0's from a random mod 2 matrix

Tags: optimization

I am fairly new to optimization problems, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

That said, I'm trying to write a program that takes an NxM matrix randomly filled with 0's and 1's, then reduces this matrix by selectively deleting rows and columns. Ultimately, I want a (N - a)x(M - b) matrix where every ijth value equals 1 should such a matrix exist.

There are two constraints: Constraint 1) N - a > c for some c > 0 (I.e., there is a minimum number of rows); Constraint 2) Using the 1st constraint, out of all possible solutions I want the most optimized. (I.e., Max[(N-a)*(M-b)] or the greatest number of 1's remaining.)

In my opinion, this is a good beginners exercise. The approach I've thought of so far is:

Step 1) for every row and column, find it's % 0's, then take the % 0's for all the columns/rows respectively that intersect this row/column with 0.

Step 2) Penalize "double" deletions of 1's (I.e., if I deleted a 1 in row 5 by removing column 16 then later had to delete row 5) by multiplying every individual row or column % with (L+s)/(M) where L is the current row/column length, s is the number of 0's previously deleted in this row/column, and M is the original row/column length.

Step 3) Further penalize row deletions by multiplying a row group average % by 1 - r/(N - c - k) where N is the original total number of rows, c is the minimum number of rows, k is the number of rows deleted thus far, and r is the number of rows pending deletion.

Step 4) Find the distance in standard deviations from each row or column % 0's to the mean % 0's of the respective column/row group described above. If there are less than 3 members of the respective group, calculate the real line distance instead.

Step 5) Delete the row/column or respective column/row group with the largest positive distance, repeat steps 1-5 until a matrix containing only 1's is obtained.

Does this method make sense? Is there a simpler or more elegant approach? Can it be done without iteration, or be solved exactly? Any advice and/or criticism is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, there was a fairly big mistake in step 1, so I edited this to fix it.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but here is a good tutorial on mathjax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . Instead of (L+s)/(M) you can write $$\frac{L+s}{M}$$ which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thank you Joao. I will edit this now, while also trying to correct my methodology (simulations commence!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About exact approaches: If you want to find the minimum number of row/column deletions, then this is equivalent to [Vertex Cover in a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29), which can be solved by matching techniques in polynomial time. If  $a$ and $b$ are fixed in the input, your problem is Constraint Bipartite Vertex Cover, which is NP-hard (see for example [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-69311-6_10)). However, you have as objective to minimize the number of remaining 1s, which is slightly different from these two. Still, the techniques used for these two problems might be useful.